# Datatables warning(table id = 'example'): cannot reinitialise data table

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I am working with datatables example and getting an error like this when loading page:
Datatables warning(table id = 'example'): cannot reinitialise data table.
To retrieve the DataTables object for this table, pass no arguments or see the docs for bRetrieve and bDestroy.

I was trying to test the fnRowCallback

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
  <html>

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <title>DataTables live example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="DataTables/media/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script class="jsbin" src="http://datatables.net/download/build/jquery.dataTables.nightly.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      @import "DataTables/media/css/demo_table.css";
    </style>
  </head>

  <body id="dt_example">
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').dataTable();
      });

      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').dataTable({
          "fnRowCallback": function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
            // Bold the grade for all 'A' grade browsers
            if (aData[4] == "A") {
              $('td:eq(4)', nRow).html('<b>A</b>');
            }
          }
        });
      });
    </script>

    <div id="container">
      <h1>Live example</h1>

      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Rendering engine</th>
            <th>Browser</th>
            <th>Platform(s)</th>
            <th>Engine version</th>
            <th>CSS grade</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr class="odd gradeX">
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>Internet Explorer 4.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+</td>
            <td class="center"> 4</td>
            <td class="center">X</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="even gradeC">
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>Internet Explorer 5.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+</td>
            <td class="center">5</td>
            <td class="center">C</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="odd gradeA">
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>Internet Explorer 5.5</td>
            <td>Win 95+</td>
            <td class="center">5.5</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="even gradeA">
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>Internet Explorer 6</td>
            <td>Win 98+</td>
            <td class="center">6</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="odd gradeA">
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>Internet Explorer 7</td>
            <td>Win XP SP2+</td>
            <td class="center">7</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="even gradeA">
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>AOL browser (AOL desktop)</td>
            <td>Win XP</td>
            <td class="center">6</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Firefox 1.0</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td class="center">1.7</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Firefox 1.5</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td class="center">1.8</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <th>Rendering engine</th>
            <th>Browser</th>
            <th>Platform(s)</th>
            <th>Engine version</th>
            <th>CSS grade</th>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>

  </html>
```

What am i doing wrong in this?

Comment: I got this error for using `$( '#example' ).dataTable()` twice. When I removed one of them, error has gone away.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You are initializing datatables twice, why?

```
// Take this off
/*
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( '#example' ).dataTable();
} );
*/
$(document).ready( function() {
  $( '#example' ).dataTable( {
   "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
     // Bold the grade for all 'A' grade browsers
     if ( aData[4] == "A" )
     {
       $('td:eq(4)', nRow).html( '<b>A</b>' );
     }
   }
 } );
 } );
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me in React.

Answer (score 204):

Try adding "bDestroy": true to the options object literal, e.g.

```
$('#dataTable').dataTable({
    ...
    ....
    "bDestroy": true
});
```

Source: [iodocs.com](https://iodocs.com/jquery/datatables-warningtable-id-example-cannot-reinitialise-data-table-2/)

or **Remove the first**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable();
} );
```

In your case is the best option **vjk**.

Comment: Important to notice that even though this will fix the issue, it does not tackles the original problem, that is the unnecessary duplicated initialization of Datatables.

Comment: this will stop further execution, like sorting

Answer (score 73):

You can also destroy the old `datatable` by using the following code before creating the new `datatable`:

```
$("#example").dataTable().fnDestroy();
```

Answer (score 49):

Add  "bDestroy": true in your dataTable Like:-

```
   $('#example').dataTable({
    ....
    stateSave: true,
    "bDestroy": true
    });
```

It Will Work.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. It worked like a charm for me. Awesome.

Comment: Just what I needed. I was struggling with this problem all day long yesterday. You saved my life. Thanks.

Comment: double awesome :)

Answer (score 30):

You can add `destroy:true` to the configuration to make sure data table already present is removed before being reinitialized.

```
$('#example').dataTable({
    destroy: true,
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 18):

You have to destroy the datatable and empty the table body before binding DataTable by doing this below,

```
function Create() {
if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#dataTable')) {
    $('#dataTable').DataTable().destroy();
}
$('#dataTable tbody').empty();
//Here call the Datatable Bind function;}
```

Answer (score 10):

This problem occurs if we initialize dataTable more than once.Then we have to remove the previous.

On the other hand we can destroy the old datatable in this way also before creating the new datatable use the following code :

```
$(“#example”).dataTable().fnDestroy();
```

There is an another scenario ,say you send more than one ajax request which response will access same table in same template then we will get error also.In this case fnDestroy method doesn’t work properly because you don’t know which response comes first or later.Then you have to set `bRetrieve TRUE` in data table configuration.That’s it.

This is My senario:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

        $('#DatatableNone').dataTable({
            "bDestroy": true
        }).fnDestroy();

        $('#DatatableOne').dataTable({
            "aoColumnDefs": [{
                "bSortable": false,
                "aTargets": ["sorting_disabled"]
            }],
            "bDestroy": true
        }).fnDestroy();

});

</script>
```

Comment: I Refered [Here](http://suvashblog.wordpress.com/2013/07/26/datatables-warningtable-id-example-cannot-reinitialise-data-table/)

Comment: Thanks dude,Quiet Helpful

Comment: Your scenario worked me..!

Answer (score 8):

```
$('#example').dataTable();
```

Make it a class so you can instantiate multiple table at a time

```
$('.example').dataTable();
```

Comment: +1 in other scenario its also working :). I don't know why its not working in my scenario. :(

Answer (score 6):

https://datatables.net/reference/option/retrieve

```js
$('#example').dataTable({
    retrieve: true,
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the first:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable();
} );
```

Answer (score 2):

I know its an old question. This problem can be easily reproduced if you try to reinitialize the Datatable again.

For example in your function somewhere you are calling `$('#example').DataTable( { searching: false} );` again.

There is easy resolving this issue. Please follow the steps

1. Initialize the Datatable to a **variable rather than directly initializing  DataTable method**.

   1. For Example Instead of calling `$('#example').DataTable( { searching: false} );` try to declare it globally (or in scope of javascription that you are using) like this `var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
      searching: false
      } );`.
2. Now Whenever you are calling this method `$('#example').DataTable( { searching: false} );` **again** then before calling it perform the following actions

   3. `if (table != undefined && table != null) 
      {
      table.destroy();
      table = null;
      }`
3. Once you have followed the steps above then go ahead with re-initializing the table with **same variable without using var keyword (as you have already defined it)** i.e `table = $('#example').DataTable( {
   searching: false
   } );`

JSFiddle Code Also attached for any reference of same code http://jsfiddle.net/vibs2006/qxy4nwfg/

Answer (score 1):

Search in your code maybe you have initialized dataTable twice. You shold have like this code:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {paging: false} );
```

Only one time in your code.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the ajax call was being interfered by the data-plugin tag applied to the table. The data-plugin does background initialization and will give this error when you have it as well as yourTable.DataTable({ ... }); initialization.

From

```
 <table id="myTable" class="table-class" data-plugin="dataTable" data-source="data-source">
```

To

```
<table id="myTable" class="table-class" data-source="data-source">
```

Answer (score 0):

When searching this topic I found the solution elsewhere but adding the answer here since I had the same problem as above together with the text "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined". Cause was due to having one to many  tags in the table body.