# Datatables error after ajax call, ASP.Net

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I'm using ajax to call a partial view with a table inside a div called "div-GVPrevision". I'm using datatables, but I'm getting an error after the ajax call, and it says:

"DataTables warning: table id=GVPrevision - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3"

This is the ajax code:

```
<script>
    function GVPrevision() {
        $('#GVPrevision').DataTable({
            "aaSorting": [],
            aLengthMenu: [
                [4, -1],
                [4, "Todo"]
            ],
            responsive: false
        });
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        GVPrevision();
        $('.btnagregar').click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var data = {
                "codmov": $("#codmovf").val(),
                "fechainicio": $("#fechainiciof").val(),
                "fechatermino": $("#fechaterminof").val(),
                "rutentidad": $("#rutentidadf").val(),
                "motivo": $("#motivof").val()
            };
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Ficha/AgregarfooterPrevision",
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response.Success) {
                        $("#div-GVPrevision").load('@Url.Content("~/Ficha/GVPrevision")');
                        GVPrevision();
                    }
                    else
                        window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Prevision", "Ficha")";
                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log('Login Fail!!!');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you post your CS code?

Comment: Possibly you're initializing `DataTable` twice, by calling `GVPrevision();` in jQuery AJAX `success` result. Try removing the second call & see if the error gone away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by replacing the code with the jquery $.post() method:

```
                    if (response.Success) {
                        $.post("/Ficha/GVPrevision", function (datos) {
                            $("#div-GVPrevision").html(datos);
                            GVPrevision();
                        })
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

as i believe the Database is initialized more then once since you are not showing the whole code i can only provide you this simple but not at all recommended soln is to destroy the data table and then call the GCPervision
AGAIN its not at all recommended soln but is a soln , Just use Distroy function

```
    function GVPrevision() {
            $('#GVPrevision').DataTable({
                "aaSorting": [],
                aLengthMenu: [
                    [4, -1],
                    [4, "Todo"]
                ],
                responsive: false
            });
        }
        $(document).ready(function () {
            GVPrevision();
            $('.btnagregar').click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var data = {
                    "codmov": $("#codmovf").val(),
                    "fechainicio": $("#fechainiciof").val(),
                    "fechatermino": $("#fechaterminof").val(),
                    "rutentidad": $("#rutentidadf").val(),
                    "motivo": $("#motivof").val()
                };
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Ficha/AgregarfooterPrevision",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (response.Success) {
                $('#GVPrevision').DataTable().destroy();
                            $("#div-
         GVPrevision").load('@Url.Content("~/Ficha/GVPrevision")');
                            GVPrevision();
                        }
                        else
                            window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Prevision", "Ficha")";
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        console.log('Login Fail!!!');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have called the `DataTable` method 2 times here, one after the `document.ready` method & another in AJAX `success` method:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    GVPrevision(); // first call
    $('.btnagregar').click(function (event) {

        // data insertion here

        $.ajax({

            // other ajax options here

            success: function (response) {
                if (response.Success) {
                    $("#div-GVPrevision").load('@Url.Content("~/Ficha/GVPrevision")');
                    GVPrevision(); // second call - this will fail
                }
                else
                    window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Prevision", "Ficha")";
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log('Login Fail!!!');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

To solve this issue, you have 2 choices:

1. Remove one of the `GVPrevision` call either after `document.ready` or AJAX POST `success` part,
2. Use `destroy` method before creating another `DataTable`, together with `bDestroy` (sometimes the `destroy` method called `fnDestroy`, pick up which is the proper one for your `DataTable` version):

   ```
   function GVPrevision() {
       $('#GVPrevision').DataTable({
           "aaSorting": [],
           aLengthMenu: [
               [4, -1],
               [4, "Todo"]
           ],
           responsive: false,
           "bDestroy": true
       }).destroy(); // or fnDestroy()
   }
   ```

If you have `DataTable` version 1.10 or more, you can add `destroy: true`:

```
function GVPrevision() {
    $('#GVPrevision').DataTable({
        destroy: true // add this line
        "aaSorting": [],
        aLengthMenu: [
            [4, -1],
            [4, "Todo"]
        ],
        responsive: false,
    });
}
```

Reference:

[Warning: Cannot reinitialise DataTable](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/3) (DataTables Documentation)

[Datatables warning(table id = 'example'): cannot reinitialise data table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13708781/datatables-warningtable-id-example-cannot-reinitialise-data-table/41136718)

Comment: I tried both, removing the GVPrevision call after AJAX POST success part, and after document.ready (so I left it after the ajax post success part), but the results are the same, the datatables stops working after the ajax call.

Comment: @DavidM Have you found any errors reported by browser console? Check if `GVPrevision` contains proper data to be loaded on DataTable after successful response.